# If the limit as k goes to the infinity of the series from n=k to positive infinity is 0, can I conclude that this series is convergent?

Tags: sequences-and-series

I think it is wrong but I cannot think of any counterexamples. If it is true, could you provide some structures of proof?

Comment: You cannot conclude that the series is convergent just because the limit of the series as k approaches infinity is 0. This is because the series could still be divergent, even if the limit of the tail of the series is zero. To see why, consider the harmonic series $1 + 1/2 + 1/3 + 1/4 + ...$

Comment: @rumathe Your comment is correct but you did not read the question correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can stop looking for a counterexample. The claim is correct.

Your hypothesis says that for each $k$ the all  the sums from $k$ to $k+n$ can made as small as you please by choosing $k$ large enough. That means that the sequence of partial sums of the original series is a Cauchy sequence, hence converges to a limit.

Comment: Sequence of partial sums is Cauchy is only a necessary condition for the convergence of a series, and it is not sufficient. Cauchy sequence does not necessarily converge in all metric spaces, and in particular, it does not necessarily converge in the space of real numbers.

Comment: @rumathe No. Every Cauchy sequence converges.  The real numbers with the usual metric is a complete metric space.

Comment: Wait, so this means that the statement is correct if we deal will reals, right? (I'm just in the first year of college, don't know what's metric spaces or things like that, hahahahah.

Comment: Yes, the statement is correct for the real numbers. The part of my comment about complete metric spaces was addressed to @rumathe